# pelican make serve error with broken pipe?

Tags: python, python-2.7, ubuntu, makefile, server

I was trying to make a blog with pelican, and in the step of make serve I had below errors. By searching online it looks like a web issue ( I'm not familiar with these at all ) and I didn't see a clear solution. Could anyone shed some light on? I was running on Ubuntu with Python 2.7. Thanks!
Python info:

> Python 2.7.6 (default, Jun 22 2015, 17:58:13) [GCC 4.8.2] on linux2

Error info:

> 127.0.0.1 - - [13/Sep/2016 13:23:35] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 - WARNING:root:Unable to find / file. WARNING:root:Unable to find /.html
>   file.
>   127.0.0.1 - - [13/Sep/2016 13:24:31] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
>   ---------------------------------------- Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 51036) Traceback (most recent
>   call last):   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 295, in
>   _handle_request_noblock
>       self.process_request(request, client_address)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 321, in process_request
>       self.finish_request(request, client_address)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 334, in finish_request
>       self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 651, in **init**
>       self.finish()   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 710, in finish
>       self.wfile.close()   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 279, in close
>       self.flush()   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 303, in flush
>       self._sock.sendall(view[write_offset:write_offset+buffer_size]) error: [Errno 32] Broken pipe

Answer (score 0):

Well I installed pip on Ubuntu and then it all worked..

Not sure if it is a version thing..

Answer (score 0):

I can report that :

- I encountered the same problem with a python3 / pip3 installation (which is recommended now)
- the problem was apparently with the permissions on python. I simply had to run `pelican --listen` with superuser rights to make the local server work.

Also be careful to install all packets you might have installed without superuser rights with `sudo` in order to have a fully-working installation with sudo.